# How much time is required between repeated exposures to sun to prevent sunburn

Tags: skin, uv

After being in the sun, how much 'rest' is required before you can expose yourself again?

e.g. from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunburn):

> Sunburn can occur in less than 15 minutes

So if you were in a place where sunburn would occur after **15 minutes** and you stayed in the sun for **10 minutes** you shouldn't get sunburn.

**How long would you then have to stay out of the sun before you could go into the sun again for 10 minutes without getting sunburn?**

I'm pretty sure that 1 minute wouldn't be enough, but 24 hours would be fine, is there any logic as to where between those two figures it actually is?

Comment: This could depend on a number of factors such as light intensity, skin color, and more. This may be a better question for a medical expert.

Comment: It seemed more scientific than a doctor would go into. I've tried searching repeatedly for it, but all you get is medical sites that never consider how the sunburn builds up, just how long in the first instance you can stay in the sun. I figured though that everything would be relative - so if you burned after 15 minutes that would indicate how long it takes to recover?